# Is it possible to "pseudo fulfill" the LinkedIn add to profile button?

Tags: javascript, certificate, linkedin-api

It seems LinkedIn has changed the previous autofulfill button.

https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/

My question is. Is it possible, with JavaScript or somehow to fill the form fields with the information so the user can check the info and make the final click?

In my case, I need to add certifications.

Comment: Yes it's possible. All depends on how you are trying to implement it. Where is the data coming from, how do you want the form fields to be filled in (API, chrome bookmarklet...)

Comment: The data come from a Rails App that issue a course certification (UUID, title, date, and description)

Comment: Can you add what the data structure looks like and what you have tried so far?

Comment: the data is simple:
 course_title, origin_entity, description, date_of_issue

I have tried to add to the route ?param1=value1&param2=value2&.... and #param1=value1&param2=value2&....